# Storing time (periods) (Specific hours) (Durations) using HTML/PHP - Days/Hours

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, google-maps

I have been working on a page that stores opening hours of days of the week using html and php to the database. In order to use the data entries to compare it with the current time.. I did my best but its not working. I'm gonna show you the html, php, sql codes so you can tell me how can I solve it.

HTML+CSS Code of the form:

http://jsfiddle.net/Naz970/4y4sd91u/

SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `markers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `days` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `openingHours` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `img` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=51
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    include ("../Connections/Connection.php");



    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $type = $_POST["type"];
        $address = $_POST["address"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $link = $_POST["link"];
        $lng = $_POST["lng"];
        $lat = $_POST["lat"];
        $days = implode(";", $_POST['days']);
        $openingHours = implode(";", $_POST['openingHours']);
        $img = time().$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],'../Uploads/'.$img))  die("error");

         $sql = "INSERT INTO markers (name,  type, address, email, phone, link, lng, lat, days, openingHours, img)
         VALUES('$name', '$type', '$address', '$email', '$phone', '$link', '$lng', '$lat', '$days', '$openingHours', '$img')";

         $query = mysql_query($sql);

         if (!$query) {
                die("Error : " . mysql_error());
            }
         if (empty($name) || empty($type) || empty($address) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($lng) || empty($lat) || empty($days) || empty($openingHours) || empty($img)) {
         echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
                die();  // Note this
            }
       echo "<center></center>";
        }


        ?>
```

But the form (the time table (schedule)) is not working and not storing the data properly. I am using it to do the following:

PHP code of the marker comparison

```
<?php
require("config.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&apos;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE

    $days = explode(";", $row['days']);
  $openingHours = explode(";", $row['openingHours']);

  $currentTime = date('H');


  if (in_array($currentTime, $openingHours)) {
      $status = 'Open';
  }
  else {
      $status = 'Closed';
  }

  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo 'status="' . $status . '" ';
  echo 'currentTime="' . $currentTime . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

I know the code is long but this is the only way to show you so you can tell me how can fix the issue of time of opening hour and link it with the marker and the current time.

If you have any question dont hesitate to ask me
Thanks in advance

Comment: you're doing your insert before `if (empty($name) || empty($type)...` why? that should go before it. you'll get empty entries doing it that way

Comment: @Fred-ii- it works both ways, but this is not what I am asking.. but thanks anyway.. help me store time into the database as the html form requires if you can... using the status of the day and the period of time (hours)

Comment: you should be storing your date/time as date-time related and not varchar --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Not working... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I did it says, use mysqli !

Comment: it says to use mysqli_* or PDO because mysql_* (without "i") is deprecated for a long time now and won't be supported in future releases of php. 
1. Do not store Date into varchar field (sorting is impossible) store it in DateTime
2. For picking date use something already written as: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
3.  Maybe an answer: Check if your implode of days is longer than 100 characters (Limit of your varchar field)!